# Scoreboard not visible in minecraft plugin

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I need help on how to show a scoreboard under players name that shows their health. The problem is that I can't see it. Here is the code:

```
@EventHandler
public void PlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    final Player p = e.getPlayer();
    ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
    final Scoreboard board = manager.getNewScoreboard();
    final Objective objective = board.registerNewObjective("showhealth", Criterias.HEALTH);
    objective.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.BELOW_NAME);
    objective.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "❤");
    p.setScoreboard(board);
    p.setHealth(p.getHealth());
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you registered the event?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to register the event.

Use `Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(listener,plugin);` at `onEnable()`

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Listener(),this);
}
```

Instead of `new Listener()` could also be this if your EventHandler is also at the main class

I also recommend you to use a later `BukkiRunnable` onPlayerJoin to leave the system register correctly the player.